# Invalid association `account` in schema Project.Feature, associated schema Project.Account does not exist

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am using ecto many_to_many relationship for 2 tables Accounts and Features. It works on my dev MacBook. However, when I push my code to circleci, it always complains

> Invalid association `account` in schema Project.Feature, associated
>   schema Project.Account does not exist.

Then it failed with

> CompileError:Project.Account.struct/1 is undefined.

I spent a few hours to figure out the issue but I am still stuck. Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Case sensitivity pops in mine mind.. Because it looks like you use the code on two  diffenct OS systems MacBook (MacOS) and circleci (no idea which OS but most likely not MacOS)

Comment: Could you include some code example?

Comment: Ensuring that circle is running the migration and the DB is correctly setup is worth looking into.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad. I renamed the file from user_account.ex to account.ex and didn't push it to circleci.